# Is it possible to extend type values in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I have the following type on a library project:

```
export type MyType = 'value1' | 'value2';
```

Is it possible to modify the type to add values in a project consuming the library?

```
import { MyType } from 'my-library';

// What can I do to add a new value to the type?
const myValue: MyType = 'value3';
```

Comment: No, you would have to declare a new type like `type MyNewType = MyType | 'value3'`. Otherwise you would be able to pass `'value3'` to functions in `my-library` which are not designed to accept it.

Comment: I would say that's anti pattern. Ruins purpose to strongly typed checking

Comment: If you control the library you can refactor so that it exports an interface and computes the union from it.  Interfaces can be reopened, so that allows [this sort of thing](https://tsplay.dev/w2421m) to happen.  If you don't control the library all you can do is use your own types and/or fork the library.